# How come I keep getting Run time Error Mismatch 13?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Cells(4, 8).Value = "0" Then Sheets(i).Cells(4, 8).Value = ".0001"
    If Sheets(i).Cells(3, 17).Value = "" Then Sheets(i).Cells(3, 17).Value = "x"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I wrote this code to look through all tabs and if these values exist to replace them. I have two different excel files. It works no problem on worksheet but Run time Error Mismatch 13 on the other one. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably one of those cells contains an error value.

Comment: Thanks will check and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need *numeric* values, not text:

```
If Sheets(i).Cells(4, 8).Value = 0 Then Sheets(i).Cells(4, 8).Value = 0.0001
```